# How to use java apache poi create default style in MS word?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I'm using Apache poi to generate the MS word report. Is there any way to set the table style to the blue one? As shown below.

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Create a file like that in Word, save it, open it as a template and populate from that?

Comment: let me try it. thank

Comment: I don't copy table in other document.